# p5.js - animate a line from two points in a related time

Tags: javascript, animation, canvas, p5.js

I'm trying to animate a line starting from a point to another. I'd like to set an animation duration, 10 minutes for example, using a variable to pass the trip duration:

```js
let p1_x = 200;
let p1_y = 200;
let p2_x = 200;
let p2_y = 300;
let run_x = p1_x;
let run_y = p1_y;


function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);
}

function draw() {
  background(220);
  noFill();
  stroke(0);
  point(p1_x, p1_y);
  point(p2_x, p2_y);
  let d = int(dist(p1_x, p1_y, p2_x, p2_y));
  stroke(0, 153, 255);
  
  if(run_x < p2_x) {
    run_x = run_x + 0.1;
  } else if(run_y < p2_y) {
    run_y = run_y + 0.1;
  }
  
  line(p1_x, p1_y, run_x, run_y);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/p5@1.2.0/lib/p5.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable timer is how many seconds*10 the program lasts. Variable t goes up whenever it irritates. When t is equal to the timer, the draw function stops using the noLoop(); function [To restart it, you have to do loop()]. I also made the line increase by the distance divided by the timer, so the line should reach the end destination perfectly when the timer ends. Tell me if this doesn't work.

```
    let p1_x = 200;
    let p1_y = 200;
    let p2_x = 200;
    let p2_y = 300;
    let run_x = p1_x;
    let run_y = p1_y;
    let timer = 600;
    let d = int(dist(p1_x, p1_y, p2_x, p2_y));
    let t = 0;    

    function setup() {
      createCanvas(400, 400);
      frameRate(10);

    }
    
 function draw()
{
      background(220);
      noFill();
      stroke(0);
      point(p1_x, p1_y);
      point(p2_x, p2_y);
      stroke(0, 153, 255);
      
      if(run_x < p2_x) {
        run_x = run_x + 0.1;
      } else if(run_y < p2_y) {
        run_y = run_y+(d/timer);
      }
      
      line(p1_x, p1_y, run_x, run_y);
  
      if(t>=timer)
        {
          noLoop();
          console.log("Works")
        }
      t++;
    }
```